# Autoloading Custom Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, config, autoload

I have a folder in `app/models` called `form_objects`.

It contains a file called `scoped_search.rb` that defines a class:

```
class ScopedSearch

end
```

In `application.rb` I have:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/form_objects)
```

Rails loads this class when it starts, but doesn't pick up changes without a restart.

**How should I ensure that this file is autoloaded?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do, actually what I currently do:

- `app/form_objects` (folder)
- `app/form_objects/form_objects.rb`
- `app/form_objects/form_objects` (folder)
- `app/form_objects/form_objects/scoped_search.rb`

`app/form_objects/form_objects.rb` contains:

```
module FormObjects
end
```

`app/form_objects/form_objects/scoped_search.rb` should be:

```
module FormObjects
  class ScopedSearch

  end
end
```

This way everything is clearly namespaced + no need to add any autoload config

Comment: Thanks. How would you then use `ScopedSearch` in a controller? do you require it? Do you refer to it using the `FormObjects` namespace?

Comment: yes always `::FormObjects::ScopedSearch`, namespacing makes things clear and avoids collision

Comment: FWIW Had issues because I had required the `form/objects/scoped_search` which was preventing Rails from autoloading it when it changed.